# Ambient Occulsion Artifacts.

Tags: baking

[image]

I'm working on a Tie Fighter and can't figure out why my wings have small black triangles (left/right) during the AO baking.  Any clues what may be going on?

Comment: Is there any hidden objects?

Comment: No.  I found my problem is that on the wings.. those faces in particular where intersecting each other slightly on those edges =(  Sorry for the post.

Comment: Add an answer, such as "intersections in meshes cause ao artefacts". That way other can gind it in searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do to get rid of ugly triangles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47629/what-can-i-do-to-get-rid-of-ugly-triangles)